Grab bar installation for plastic shower overlying tiles
How would you install grab bars in this shower (made of some type of plastic), that appears to overlay tile, which itself overlays drywall?
My intention was to attach the grab bars using heavy duty toggle bolts, as I can't locate the studs and/or they're inconveniently located.
However, if I penetrate through the plastic, I have to contend with the tile underneath, which may crack and fall off during drilling, creating a void.
The plastic flexes a bit and there is indeed a little "space" between it and the subsurface material in some parts of the shower.
Is it possible to drill through the initial plastic with a titanium bit, then somehow know when I've reached the tile, switching to a diamond drill bit for it?
Any solutions would be well appreciated!


When you need to use a grab bar you want it to be anchored into the studs.  A sudden jerk and even toggle bolts will pull out.

The correct screws into studs are the strongest, the simplest and by far the cheapest, but grab bars can be anchored in drywall under tile with the appropriate anchors. There are a number of manufacturers that make anchors approved for this purpose.

Grab bar anchors for drywall require a larger hole 3/4" or more and the anchor slips in and expands or rotates a flat toggle behind the drywall. It clamps onto the back side of the drywall.  This is very strong and  could not be pulled out by any person who needed a grab bar.

Ordinary toggle bolts are not stainless steel (neither the bolts nor the toggles). They would rust over time in a shower.

Where is this house, city and state?

Installing grab bars in a shower:

Plan how many bars, their length and location.

Check for studs near the ends of the planned locations. Sometimes the bar location or length is changed to allow attachment to a stud on one or both ends. A bar can be screwed into a stud on one end and fastened with a drywall anchor on the other end. A well designed shower or tub shower will have 2x6" horizontal blocking in the walls where one would want a grab bar, but it is hard to determine whether blocking is present without drilling.

If there are no studs close to the location of the ends, then you will have to use anchors on both ends.

If there is plastic over tile on drywall, AND there is an air gap between the plastic and the tile, then a special supporting spacer/shim must be placed between the plastic and the tile otherwise the plastic would deform or tear. If there is no air gap, then no shim is needed.

What are the dimensions of the shower and where do you want the grab bars? Is this a high step over tub/shower or is this a low sill shower? Does it have a shower curtain or glass door?


I have installed about a dozen bathroom grab bars in our 2-bath house and a 2-bath house of a relative. The walls are ceramic tile on cement board. Our bathrooms have bathroom ceramic tiles on 1/2" thick cement board. I just used regular plastic anchors of the size for the stainless steel screws that come with the grab bars (two screws per end). In spite of claims that this is not acceptable, I found that these these are very secure. This only requires at most a 3/8" hole per screw. I might try this on tile-on-drywall, but it might not work on just drywall.
EDIT
https://youtu.be/qqZ9rk7vqkM?si=TZjiORy9Opar73iV
https://youtu.be/toXPkYGNkaA?si=00fmFerGupZIb_1W

Hi @Jim Stewart, thanks so much for the response. I really appreciate the plan of attack you  outlined. My apologies for the late response on my end -- was contending with other concerns related to the health crisis of the family member necessitating these grab bars.
Thank you also for the tip on the plastic anchors -- I'll keep that in mind for the future. This home was constructed in the late 60s and a lot of things are not up to code. I wouldn't be surprised if the tiles are laid over regular drywall, as opposed to cement board or even green board.

All the authorities say not to rely on regular plastic wall anchors for shower grab bars. The first grab bar I installed was a vertical shoulder-height  18" bar to assist in stepping into and out of the 14" step-over tub/shower that I use. I thought I had located a stud right where I wanted the bar and confidently drilled with a ceramic bit through the tile, the backer board expecting to hit the stud. At that point I planned change to a smaller diameter wood bit and drill 1.5" into the stud. However the drill went into empty space . . . @#$%!  I just decided to try the regular anchors. Worked!

When you get ready to actually install or even to plan, give more detail about the wall so I and others can give detailed suggestions.

If the shower user is really at risk of falling, is really feeble, then grab bars might not be enough. It might require a transfer bench and a sit down shower. If grab bars are deemed sufficent, you MUST have a rubber non-slip mat in any metal tub and maybe in a fiberglass tub. Plastic shower pans or tile usually have a non-slip surface that works without a rubber mat.
